# How to move whole text on the image to right side without moving the image position?

Tags: html, css

was search around but can't find the answer I need, I am good. Still learning. Hopefully, someone can help me out.

For example the problem show now on my learning web was:

my problem now
[image]
The title and whole paragraph was at left place on the image...

I wish to move the title and whole paragraph of content to right side without moving the position on the image to get this result:

I want to get this result
[image]

this was the original code:

```css
.intro-section {
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 17;
  padding: 80px 0;
  margin-top: -86px;
  background: url(../images/img.jpg) no-repeat top center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.intro-section h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.intro-section .image-holder {
  margin-top: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1>  title </h1>
        content paragraph xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hopefully can get an answer here, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Add This Class `col-md-offset-6` on `col-md-6`

```
 <div class="intro-section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-6">
                        <h1>  title </h1>
    
                     content paragraph xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                </div>
           </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: wow, just follow your way, its works perfectly, and i get the result i want, thank you very much 

Answer (score 0):

You can place the img in a separate `div` and text in another and then use `text-align` property and set to `center`, it will align the text to center and then you can place that img where ever you want

Comment: thanks, Mr.Lalji already taught me to get the result : )